# Redundant mailservers. Route messages from internal users to secondary site

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, zimbra

I have 2 mailservers running ZIMBRA  (primary - site1) and (secondary - site2) in two separated locations (sites).

When my primary mailserver in AVAILABLE the seconray are just syncing (rsync) with his zimbra services down. Just when the primary goes down is that my secondary mailserver starts the Zimbra services and became available to receiving email messages.

How my internal users (webmail and clients like thunderbird/outlook) in the primary location (site1) will send the messages to secondary server if my Primary MailServer at SITE1 goes down? An email coming from outside it's OK, because we have 2 MX entries (primary and secondary mailservers), but the internal users in the same network dont send the email messages to MX server, they deliver the message directly to mailserver.

This is how my setup looks like: http://postimg.org/image/l2l7aziex/

Any thoughts?

Many Tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change the DNS records for mail.mydomain.com (or whatever your clients use for SMTP/IMAP addresses) to point to the secondary server until the problem is fixed.

That's assuming both servers have the same accounts, same mailbox contents, etc.

Comment: But how can I do this automaticamente? I wouldnt like to every time that a failure happen the need to manualy do that.

Comment: That completely depends on how your DNS is setup, what software it uses, what you have monitoring for failures, etc.  But the changes can be scripted and triggered by a monitoring system.  Though if it fails often enough that doing it manually is a large concern...I'd work on making the server more reliable in the first place.

Comment: Sure! I will take a look at KeepAlived, as well. (www.keepalived.org).